# how to use datatable.compute for division in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

i am using divion operator in c# as below and getting an error like `Specified cast is not valid`,any reason behind it

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    int answer = (int)dt.Compute("(1*4000*700*20)/4000", "");
```

Comment: why dont you pass this to SP instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems that it is returning double.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
double answer = (double)dt.Compute("(1*4000*700*20)/4000", ""); 
Console.Write(answer);
```

Comment: now getting Value is either too large or too small for Type 'Int32'

Comment: Fixed by adding ".0"

Answer (score 1):

use `Convert()` instead of casting to get a `int` result

```
int answer = Convert.ToInt32(new DataTable().Compute("(1*4000*700*20)/4000", ""));
```

Comment: now getting Value is either too large or too small for Type 'Int32'

Comment: Fixed by adding ".0"